# Run external commands from Scribes

Tags: command-line, text-editor

Can I run external commands from Scribes?

I'm looking for functionality similar to gedit's External Tools. I would like to be able to run an arbitrary command from Scribes via a chosen key command, e.g. to run `latexmk` on the current file when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP posted answer in question

> I found https://answers.launchpad.net/scribes/+question/146309 which suggests that it's not currently possible.